# How do you use timeit to time how long it takes a function to run?

Tags: python, timer, timeit

Trying to figure out how long it takes this piece of code to run:

```
import timeit as t

def fib_recursive(n):

    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)
print fib_recursive(29)
print t.Timer("fib_recursive(29)")
```

Output was the following:

514229
timeit.Timer instance at 0xda28c0

Comment: you can use [`t.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on thefourtheye's comment (which is correct), you generally want to isolate the steps necessary to define a function into the setup parameter for `timeit`. Given your setup, I would do the following:

```
import timeit as t

def fib_recursive(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib_recursive(n-1) + fib_recursive(n-2)

setup = 'from __main__ import fib_recursive'
t.timeit('fib_recursive(29)', setup=setup)
```

I'll assume that you're aware of the various techniques to improve this algorithm and are choosing to measure its speed to establish a baseline only. You can experiment with the `number` keyword parameter to `timeit` to control the number of repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

When you use IPython, the easiest way for timing is using the magicfunction `%timeit`:

```
%timeit fib_recursive(10)
>>> 10000 loops, best of 3: 70.2 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`timeit.Timer.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit):

```
timer = t.Timer("fib_recursive(29)", setup='from __main__ import fib_recursive')
print timer.timeit()
```

or simply use [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

```
print t.timeit("fib_recursive(29)", setup='from __main__ import fib_recursive')
```

NOTE: You need to pass `import` statement to `setup` argument.